# How to show a hidden Image View for a certain amount of time, then hide it again

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I have 4 Image Views placed on my ViewController. I wish to be able to choose which view I can see for 1 second, and then hide it again until I wish to show it again?

I wish to do this between functions being called as shown below: (I have commented where I wish to show and then hide the images)

```
`- (IBAction)buttonHit:(UIButton *)sender
{    
    AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sender.tag == 1001)
    {
        // show view 1
        [app addNote:1];
        // hide view 1

        // show view 4
        [app addNote:4];
        // hide view 4

        // show view 2
        [app addNote:2];
        // hide view 2
    }
```

I think I will need one method to show and then another to hide after 1 second?

Please can someone help me?

Comment: and what have you thought about doing? do you need to be able to cancel the sequence part way through?

Comment: I think just for now, the sequence will just run until there are no more notes declared..

Comment: I will hopefully end up with something similar to the Simon Memory game but for now I just want to get an understanding of how to show Image Views then hide them again. 'Flash' them essentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE) is what you are looking for.

From the apple docs:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
         target:self
         selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
         userInfo:[self userInfo]
         repeats:NO];
```